# Migrating to sql azure with php activerecord/Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, sql-server, codeigniter, activerecord, phpactiverecord

I want to migrate a database from MySql to cloud based Sql Azure platform.I am currently using php-Activerecord-0.0.1 with codeigniter framework and it works great with MySql.

to connect with SQL Server i tried following proceedure:

1) I was able to connect to sql server database by using SqlSrv Adapter available at  url:  https://github.com/funkjedi/php-activerecord/tree/master/lib/adapters.

2)As soon as it got connected,All existing activerecord-queries threw an error .That means all php-activerecord queries are not compatible with SqlServer db.

i got the following errors:

1) A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 0

Filename: lib/Model.php

Line Number: 1663

2) A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Uninitialized string offset: -1

Filename: adapters/SqlsrvAdapter.php

Line Number: 35

I also got some errors in present queries like:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ActiveRecord\DatabaseException' with message '42000, 1038, [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Change the alias to a valid name.' in php-activerecord\0.0.1\vendor\php-activerecord\lib\Connection.php:318 Stack trace: #0 php-activerecord\0.0.1\vendor\php-activerecord\lib\Table.php(218): ActiveRecord\Connection->query('SELECT * FROM [...', Array) #1 php-activerecord\0.0.1\vendor\php-activerecord\lib\Table.php(209): ActiveRecord\Table->find_by_sql('SELECT * FROM [...', Array, false, NULL) #2 php-activerecord\0.0.1\vendor\php-activerecord\lib\Model.php(1577): ActiveRecord\Table->find(Array) #3 C:php-activerecord\0.0.1\vendor\php-a in php-activerecord\0.0.1\vendor\php-activerecord\lib\Connection.php on line 318

Can i use php- activerecord to query sql server database? , by doing some major or minor changes in Model.php /Table.php or SQLBuider  in "php-activerecord\0.0.1\vendor\php-activerecord\lib"?

Please advice me on this.

Comment: what error did i throw? it could just be you don't have the right pdo drivers for mssql-pdo?

Comment: Thanks for your comment Nanne, I have edited my question above including errors i encountered.

Comment: one more thing,this refers to php-activerecord(http://www.phpactiverecord.org) and not the codeigniter activerecords.

Comment: That much is clear because of the tag. What is less clear, is the question (take a look at the formatting buttons and use the preview. There are buttons for quoting and for code, for example). Speaking about code, you might want to show some. What call did you do? Can you make an example with very little code that still shows the error (see http://sscce.org/ )